# No puedo usar Git Bash. fatal: bad numeric config value '=' for 'core.autocrlf': invalid unit

Tags: git

desinstale, volví a instalar, no se que mas hacer para poder usar git bash. el error es: **fatal: bad numeric config value '=' for 'core.autocrlf': invalid unit**

al querer hacer un git add . o cualquier otro comando al repositorio.

git config -l

```
    diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
credential.helper=manager
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
user.name=emiibarra6
user.email=***
winupdater.recentlyseenversion=2.24.1.windows.2
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.autocrlf==
core.autocrlf==
core.autocrlf==
```

Answer (score 1):

El archivo de configuración de GIT fue modificado con un valor incorrecto, siendo precisos el parámetro `core.autocrlf`, para corregirlo ejecuta el comando:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

También tienes los valores `false` o `input` según tus necesidades. También puedes borrar la configuración volviendo a su valor por defecto con:

```
git config --global --unset core.autocrlf
```

Si la configuración fue hecha en un repositorio local cambia `--global` por `--local`.

[Documentación de GIT](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration)

Comment: Hola, cuando ejecuto el primer git que mencionas, sale el siguiente warning **warning: core.autocrlf has multiple values
error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value
       Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change core.autocrlf.**

Comment: Y si voy a mi repo, y lo hago local, sale el mismo warning: **warning: core.autocrlf has multiple values**

Comment: Prueba aumentando --replace-all `git config --global --replace-all core.autocrlf true`, si sigue el problema dinos lo que te muestra ejecutando `git config -l`

Comment: edite la publicación, agregando el git config -l. No funcione aumentando el replace-all

Comment: Tienes un error de escritura, pusiste `tru` en lugar de `true`, de todas formas el parámetro de configuración viene sobrando ya que tu valor por defecto es `true`, puedes borrarlo con `git config --global --unset core.autocrlf`

Comment: ya lo borre, quedo solamente un parametro. Igualmente da error.

Comment: **fatal: bad numeric config value '=' for 'core.autocrlf': invalid unit**

Comment: edito el config -l en la publicación.

Comment: Ya encontre el error. Al final del config - l hay valores como 
**core.autocrlf==
core.autocrlf==
core.autocrlf==**

Comment: como borro estos? Con git config --global --unset core.autocrlf no puedo borrarlos.

Comment: Quizás estén en tu configuración local, prueba con `git config --local --unset core.autocrlf` sino quizás esté en system el mismo comando pero cambiando --local por `--system` (aunque eso es poco probable y recomendable)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103101/discussion-between-gisela-and-vlady).

Answer (score 0):

Ese error lo pude solucionar borrando el `core.autocrlf==` que esta en el `.git` en un archivo config (use block de notas, uso window), es el `.git` de mi proyecto. Espero tes sirva.